# Scanning File to find exact size of HashTable size vs constantly resizing Array and ReHashing and other questions

Tags: arrays, hashtable

So I am doing a project, that requires me to find all the anagrams in a given file. Each file has words on each line.

What I have done so far:

1.) sort the word (using Mergesort - (I think this is the best in the worst case.. right?))
2.) place into the hashtable using a hash function
3.) if there is a collision move to the next available space further in the array (basically going down one by one until you see an empty spot in the hashtable) (is there a better way for this? What I am doing in linear probing).

Problem:

When it runs out of space in the hash table.. what do I do? I came up with two solutions, either scan the file before inputing anything into the hash table and have one exact size or keep resizing the array and rehashing as it get more and more full. I don't know which one to choose. Any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Sorting is often a good idea, and I can think of a way to use it here, but there's no advantage to sorting items if all you do afterwards is put them into a hashtable.  Hashtables are designed for constant-time insertions even when the sequence of inserted items is in no particular order.
- Mergesort is one of several sorting algorithms with O(nlog n) worst-case complexity, which is optimal if all you can do is compare two elements to see which is smaller.  If you can do other operations, like index an array, O(n) sorting can be done with radixsort -- but it's almost certainly not worth your time to investigate this (especially as you may not even need to sort at all).
- If you resize a hashtable by a constant *factor* when it gets full (e.g. doubling or tripling the size) then you maintain constant-time inserts.  (If you resize by a constant *amount*, your inserts will degrade to linear time per insertion, or quadratic time over all n insertions.)  This might seem wasteful of memory, but if your resize factor is k, then the proportion of wasted space will never be more than (k-1)/k (e.g. 50% for doubling).  So there's never any asymptotic execution-time advantage to computing the exact size beforehand, although this may be some constant factor faster (or slower).
- There are a variety of ways to handle hash collisions that trade off execution time versus maximum usable density in different ways.